# Isolating title and text Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a some code that parses out a div from a page then finds all "p" tags which will have a title and some some text

sample:

```
for fn in os.listdir('.'):
     if os.path.isfile(fn):

        url = "%s/%s" % (path, fn)
        page = open(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')

        soup2 = soup.find("div", {"class": "aui-field-wrapper-content"})

        print soup2.p.prettify()

        for node in soup2.findAll('p'):
                print ''.join(node.findAll(text=True))
```

which returns

sample:

```
<p>
 <b>
  <strong class="TooltipInline" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Molecular formula">
   Mol. formula:
  </strong>
 </b>
 C23H30O6
</p>
```

In this instance i want to individually access the title Mol. Formula: and the text "C23H30O6" currently I am able to return
 Mol. formula: C23H30O6 but not the individual components. I am realtively new to beautiful soup and am unsure of how to reference each component of a "p" tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way to approach the problem is to get the `b` element inside the `p` element and consider it your "label", then [go sideways and get the next sibling element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
label = p.b
value = label.next_sibling.strip()
print(label.get_text(strip=True), value)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> data = """
... <p>
...  <b>
...   <strong class="TooltipInline" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Molecular formula">
...    Mol. formula:
...   </strong>
...  </b>
...  C23H30O6
... </p>
... """
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
>>> 
>>> p = soup.p
>>> 
>>> label = p.b
>>> value = label.next_sibling.strip()
>>> print(label.get_text(strip=True), value)
Mol. formula: C23H30O6
```

Comment: This is actually a great response as well perhaps even more elegant... do you think there is any difference in performance being as I want to iterate through several million of these html files???

Comment: @TylerCowan this should be faster than the other answer, but I dont expect this part to be a bottleneck - see if using 'lxml' parser or 'SoupStrainer' would help with performance improvements if this matters. Thanks.

Comment: If you are iterating through millions of these files I would be more worried about being throttled/blocked by the host site.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of `findAll(text=True)` is doing the same thing as the `get_text()` method from Beautiful Soup.  It will get all the text in the `<p>` tag.  If you have a stable format a simple way to do it would be:

```
ptext = node.get_text().split(':',1)
title = ptext[0].strip()
value = ptext[1].strip()
```

In reference to the child tag question note that the molecular formula isn't in any tag except for the `<P>` tag.

Comment: Ok that is a good solution as I do have a relatively stable format. do you know how I can directly reference the p tag as I have say 10 of them and only want  to reference say 3 with a specific title??

Comment: I guess I can just use logical operators :p

Comment: The problem is that the `<P>` tag doesn't have an attribute itself.  You could get all the `<strong>` tags with a title of Molecular formula and then navigate up to the parent something like `strongnode.parent.parent.get_text()`